# Multiple rows Color Scale

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns, F and H. The data is between F2-F75 and H2-H75. F has the required stock level. H says how much stock is needed.

I would like to make a Conditional Formatting rule for every row in column H that formats the cell with a colour to show how much stock is required, by looking at the corresponding cell in column F. This works fine for a single row, but I have 75 rows, and manually creating a new rule for each row will take a long time. I have tried using the format painter which works for changing which cell the rule applies to, but it does not change the maximum cell to the respective one, it keeps it as is from the original formula. I have tried setting the maximum to:

```
=$F$2:$F$75
```

but this returns the error:

> This type of reference cannot be used in a Conditional Formatting formula. Change the reference to a single cell, or use the reference with a worksheet function, such as =SUM(A1:E5).

This works fine for H2-F2, but I would like to have it for H2-H75 and F2-F75:

[image]

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: I think you'll need VBA to do this. I've messed around a bit with per-row color scales and posted some on it, but haven't ever dealt with this bit. I think if you recorded a macro of applying it to one row, you could turn it into a loop pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks, Doug. I just tried creating a macro but it keeps the maximum formula as the one I recorded. I recorded the macro by creating a new rule for H2, using F2 as the maximum formula in the rule. Then when I ran the formula on H3, it still had F2 as the maximum, instead of F3. Is there a way to make it just select the cell that is 2 rows over such as H3-2 or something?

Comment: I just found this formula in another post.

=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),0,-1)

This seems to work in selecting the cell to the left. I just changed the -1 on the end to -2, so it selects the cell from column F. This seems to work, the H column is changing to red when stock is needed, however it's not showing the 3 colour gradation from red-to-yellow-to-blue. If any stock is needed it shows as red, but if no stock is needed it shows as blue. When I change the stock on hand value, I can see it turns yellow but almost instantly changes to red.

Comment: Sorry, I wish I had time to look at this. I'm not surprised the OFFSET doesn't work, but can't explain what you're seeing. To do the macro, you'll need to build the formula in a string, based on the active row or the index of a loop. In other words, your code would supply the relative reference.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Frjkeaq.png

This solution is working for me. I have 3 separate rules for each colour.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/837073-conditional-formatting-multiple-rows-color-scale.html#post4079719

Comment: That makes sense. I'm glad it worked for you. To be clear, I think, you've gone from a color scale to discrete rules, which do tend to be easier to manipulate (as long as you don't need too many of them!).